# How to attach EIP to a existing ENI (Created outside of terraform) using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

Hello I'm trying to attach EIP to ENI using terraform. Both EIP and ENI are created outside of terraform.

Following are the manual steps:

- Need to allocate a IP address in subnet for the ENI
- Associate EIP to the ENI on the previously allocated IP address.

Is there anyway to automate this using terraform ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Looks like terraform natively doesn't support requesting private ip to ENI. So used [data external](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) resource to create a secondary ip to existing ENI and used "[aws_eip_association](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eip_association)" resource to associate EIP to ENI on Private IP created using data external resource.